# How can I select an option by the value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, html-select

I wanted to select an option from a form. If I select this option, Javascript should check if the value/content is ex. "B".
How can Javascript now check if the value/content of this option is B or is not B?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var text = document.form1.fahrstunden;
    function a(){
        if (document.form1.klasse.options[klasse.option.value=B].selected == true) {
            alert("fu test");
        }
    }
</script>

<form onmousemove="a()"  id="form1" name="form1"method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" onsubmit="a()" >
    <select name="klasse" id="klasse" >
        <option  value="B" selected="selected">B</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Please re-format your question, the line-breaks are making me crazy :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add an `onchange` function:

```
document.getElementById("klasse").onchange = function() {
    alert(this.value);
}
```

You can then compare that value to whatever you need, ex:

```
if (this.value == "B") {
    //value is B, do stuff!
}
```

Side note: the `this.value` is pulled from the `value` attribute of the option. If you want the actual text, you can do the following:

```
var selectedText = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/U7KKF/

Comment: Glad i could help, be sure to mark it as correct when you can.